# При ajax подгрузке почему-то отрабатывает только первое условие if

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть фрагмент кода с `ajax` подгрузкой информации и вызова функции сразу после этого. Как сделать так, чтобы в случае самого первого запроса вызывалась страница приветствия, а после клика на кнопку загружалась функция с контентом. Делаю так, но каждый раз почему-то загружается первый блок `if` и даже при обновлении страницы счетчик `count` не растет, а сбрасывается.

```js
$(function() {
  var pathToSome = 'some.php';

  var count = 0;

  $.get(pathToSome, function(data) {

    if (count === 0) {
      $('#content').html("<h1>Стартовая страница</h1><p><a href="#">Перейти</a></p>");

    } else {
      someFunction();
      console.log("Do some function");
    }
    count++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `count` вынести за `$(function() {`.

Comment: @Suvitruf попробовал, эффекта не дало, `count` все равно обнуляется

Answer (score 1):

Если вам требуется, чтобы переменная оставалась в памяти после перезагрузки страницы, то нужно ее хранить где-то, например, в кэше или local storage. 
Тогда, после того, как пользователь зайдет на страницу, счетчик можно увеличивать или завести переменную типа boolean.

Если при перезагрузке страницы count не нужен, то можно просто блок приветствия скрывать при клике на кнопку.

Comment: делаю так, но все равно не получается..
`localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'true'); 
var localValue = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
$(function(){
        $.get(pathToPolls, function(data) {
          if (localValue) { localStorage.removeItem("myKey"); localStorage.clear(); }
else {...}`
 });

Comment: @Вася Если я правильно поняла, что вам после того, как пользователь при первом входе увидел приветствие, нужно его больше не показывать, то при загрузке страницы надо сделать `localStorage.setItem('helloIsSeen', 'false');`, потом при успешной отработке запроса `localStorage.setItem('helloIsSeen', 'true');`. В `if` поставить проверку на `helloIsSean` - то есть пользователь увидел приветствие. Тогда, если он увидел, то будет выполняться то, что в `else`. В вашем коде вы очищаете `localStorage` при каждой загрузке, значение переменной становится `true` и выполняется опять очистка.

Answer (score 0):

переменная  var count = 0; она у тебя так объявленна, а после получения ответа ты ее не пересчитываешь. как писали выше, вынеси ее выше по коду за пределы функции. а так получается что при каждом запуске функции ты определяешь ее как равную нулю.